# InkAnalyzer UWP - custom shapes

Tags: c#, uwp, inkcanvas, ink-analyzer

Just wondering - is there a way to add custom shape recognition to UWP ink analyzer?

I need to be able to recognize a semi-circle, an arrow an couple of other simple shapes.

What is the best approach to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I known, we can not recognize a semi-circle, an arrow an couple of other simple shapes by the `InkAnalyzer` class. It can recognize the specified shape in the `Ink​Analysis​Drawing​Kind`.

The [`Ink​Analysis​Drawing​Kind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.analysis.inkanalysisdrawingkind) enum lists Circle, Diamond, Drawing, Ellipse,
EquilateralTriangle, Hexagon, IsoscelesTriangle, Parallelogram, Pentagon, Quadrilateral, Rectangle, RightTriangle, Square, Trapezoid and Triangle. We can not add our custom shape to it.

If you draw a semi-circle, it maybe will recognize to Ellipse or Rectangle that we can not know it is a semi-circle. If you draw an arrow, it will not be recognized as one of the shapes listed. Then it will return `Ink​Analysis​Drawing​​Kind.Drawing`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was hoping this would be extensible in some way, like possibility of defining custom shapes. Are you aware of any such plans for the future versions?

Comment: @NickGoloborodko I do not know if it will be added in the future version. If you want request Microsoft to integrate the above future, you should able to request it on WPDev UserVoice in this link: [http://wpdev.uservoice.com/](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/). I can not guarantee that it will be adopted.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Microsoft/MTC_WindowsSmartInk

You can do it if you use it in conjunction with Azure's Custom Vision service. I've seen a lot of demo videos from Build about it.